# Getting model instance by variable model name and pk

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.9, and now trying to override `save` method behaviour. The problem is that when I do `instance.some_field = some_value`, the `self` object is already modified, whereas I need to know that was the original value of `some_field`. To do this, the only way out seems to be fetching object from database by `self`'s pk.

So I wonder what is GENERIC syntax - if there's any - to fetch instance from the database? By saying GENERIC, I imply that I don't want to explicitly type the model name (like `MYMODEL.objects.get(...)`), but rather make Django figure out the right model based on target instance's model.

To make the question clearer, let me illustrate my goal in a pseudo-code:

```
def save_extented(self, *args, **kwargs):
   original_object = (self model).objects.get(pk = self.pk)
```

Is it possible ? Or maybe I don't need this, and there's some smart Django hack to fetch the instance with rolled back field values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [django-dirtyfields](http://django-dirtyfields.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) and `pre_save` signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def pre_save_logic(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if 'my_field' in instance.get_dirty_fields():
        do_some_logic()
```